# Характеристика словосочетания

Tags: синтаксис, словосочетания

Почему "три лисицы" - цельное словосочетание, а "трёх лисиц" - свободное?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что количественные числительные (исключение: один) в именительном и винительном падежах управляют существительным, ставя его в форме родительного падежа, а в остальных формах количественные числительные согласуются с существительными.

А дети, действительно, любой вопрос задать могут, но не каждый будет правильным.

Подробнее почитать можно [здесь](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200302310)

Comment: Это я попыталась сказать,ученица не поняла, ещё больше запуталась. Это ведь не студентка, а школьница. Я попыталась идти от определения:цельное - синтаксически неразложимое, занимает одну синтаксическую позицию:Три лисицы сидели...Кто?-три лисицы - подлежащее. Кто?-три - не по-русски, потому что это не кто?, а сколько? Кто?-лисицы-не подходит, потому что род. пад.Значит, неделимое, всё вместе подлежащее. Не знаю, дошло или нет, по - моему, она просто "приняла" объяснение, но не поняла. Видимо, ещё что-то надо для понимания, может, языковое чутьё,кот. далеко не у всех есть.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что нельзя спросить: "лисицы сколько?", а "лисиц сколько?" можно.

Comment: Тогда "пять лисиц" - свободное, потому что лисиц сколько?-пять можно спросить?  А если кто-то спросит: три кого? - лисицы?

Comment: А  трое:  кого ?   Можно  спросить ?